# How do I pass a pointer of type struct product to a function that creates a struct stock that has a member of type struct product?

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I have two header files: product.h which as defined

```
struct Produto{
    char* nome;
    int codigo;
    float preco;
};

typedef struct Produto* ptr_Produto;`
```

and a stock.h thas as defined

```
struct Stock{
    ptr_Produto* produto_stock;
    int stock_size;
    int id;
};
typedef struct Stock* ptr_Stock`;
```

I then have a function insertProductsInStock(stock, product, stock_lenght)that receives the struct product I want to pass to it, the pointer to an array of structs stock and the lenght of the array.
Inside that function I call another function that should return a pointer

```
stock[i] = createStock(Product_pointer, quantity, product_code_in_stock)`.
```

The function is defined like so:

```
void insertProductStock(ptr_Stock* stock, ptr_Produto* produto, int stock_size)
{
    int quantidade, codigo_stock;

    ptr_Produto temp = *produto;

    for(int i = 0; i < stock_size; i++){
        if(stock[i] == NULL){
            printf("Insert the quantity: ");
            scanf("%d", &quantidade);
            printf("Insert the code: ");
            scanf("%d", &codigo_stock);
            stock[i] = createStock(temp, 
            quantidade,codigo_stock);
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

And the function to create stock[i] is defined like:

```
ptr_Stock criarStock(ptr_Produto produto, int stock_size, int id){
    ptr_Stock stock = malloc(sizeof(ptr_Stock));

    stock->produto_stock = malloc(sizeof(ptr_Produto));
    stock->produto_stock[0] = produto;
    stock->stock_size = stock_size;
    stock->id = id;
    printf("stock criado com sucesso! \n");
    return stock;
};
```

When I print the stock it gives me NULL for the data passed to ptr_Produto* produto_stock;
What is it I am failing to do correctly?

I know that I am not passing correctly the address of the pointer product but Iḿ not seeing where is it.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Probably not causing your problem, but you should not hide pointer types in a typedef. It makes it more difficult to recognize pointers.

Comment: `ptr_Stock stock = malloc(sizeof(ptr_Stock));` is wrong as `sizeof(ptr_...)` is always the size of a pointer (usually 8 or 4 bytes). Should be `ptr_Stock stock = malloc(sizeof(Stock));` or `ptr_Stock stock = malloc(sizeof *stock);` Same appies for the next `malloc()`

Comment: @Gerhardh it si causing. OP is struggling with pointers and now he has hidden pointer to pointer.